# Как сделать многоязычнось? php

Tags: php

есть сайт на php, вход регистрация и тд, собственно хотелось бы сделать его многоязычным, посдкажите как это нормально можно сделать, хочется что то типа такого

К примеру есть папка "lang" в ней присутствуют языки к примеру ru.php, ua.php, en.php

ну и вот так выводить слова и прочее .lang('exit'). - Выход (Exit)

Comment: Обычно берётся ключ - название переменной на латинице, а значение ключа на русском, английском и других языках. Сам массив можно хранить хоть в json, хоть в базе данных, хоть в текстовике

Comment: lang файлы как в Битриксе например

Comment: Обычно используется библиотека i18n для интернационализации.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем файл-библиотеку для работы с переводами

> lang.class.php

```php
<?php
class Lang {
    const LANG_DIR = __DIR__."/langs/"; //папка где хранфятся все переводы

    private $language = "ru"; //Язык (по сути своей папка в которой может лежать куча файлов с переводами разбитыми по некоей тематике
    private $translationTable = []; //общая таблица переводов

    public function __construct( $language = "ru") {
        $this->setLanguage( $language );
    }

    /**
    * Установка языка
    * @param string $language Язык переводов
    */
    public function setLanguage( $language = null ) {
        if ( !is_null( $language ) && $this->getLanguage() != $language && ( realpath( self::LANG_DIR.$language ) !== false AND is_dir( realpath( self::LANG_DIR.$language ) ) ) ) {
            $this->language = $language;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Возвращает текущий язык переводов
    * @return string
    */
    public function getLanguage() {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
    * Возвращает текст перевода из файла $category
    * @param string $category Имя файла (без .php) в папке переводов и в подпапке языка переводов
    * @param string $message Ключ в ассоциативном массиве файла переводов
    * @param array $params Ассоциативный массив позволяющий использовать внутри текста перевода подставноку значений по алиасам
    * @return string
    */
    public function t( $category, $message, $params = [] ) {
        if ( !isset( $translationsTable[$category] ) && file_exists( self::LANG_DIR.$this->getLanguage()."/".$category.".php" ) ) {
            $translationsTable[$category] = @require_once( self::LANG_DIR.$this->getLanguage()."/".$category.".php" );
        }
        $result = ( is_array( $translationsTable[$category] ) && isset( $translationsTable[$category][ $message] ) ? $translationsTable[$category][ $message] : $message );
        foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {
            $result = ( mb_substr( $key, 0, 1 ) == "@" ? preg_replace("/\\".$key."/", $value, $result) : $result );
        }
        return $result;
    }   

}
```

Где-то в папке проекта создаем папку `langs` и в ней две подпапки `ru` и `de` (не забудьте в `lang.class.php` поправить `LANG_DIR` путь к этим папкам) - это для теста. Если Вам нужны другие языки - создайте соответствующие папки.

В каждой из них создаем два файла

> login.php (для DE)

```php
<?php
return array(
  'Account disabled' => 'Account deaktiviert',
  'Incorrect username or password' => 'Falscher Benutzername oder falsches Passwort',
);
```

> users.php (для DE)

```php
<?php
return array(
  'Please, fill the field `username`' => 'Bitte füllen Sie das Feld `Benutzername` aus',
  'Username `@username` is invalid' => 'Benutzername `@username` ist ungültig',
);
```

И тоже самое для `RU`

> login.php (для RU)

```php
<?php
return array(
  'Account disabled' => 'Аккаунт пользовател отключен',
  'Incorrect username or password' => 'неверное имя пользователя или пароль',
);
```

> users.php (для RU)

```php
<?php
return array(
  'Please, fill the field `username`' => 'Пожалуйста заполните поле `имя пользователя`',
  'Username `@username` is invalid' => 'Имя пользователя `@username` некорректно',
);
```

Ну и собственно создаем файл для проверки как работает наш класс с переводами

> test.php

```php
<?php
//Подключаем файл-библиотеку с классом переводов
include_once("lang.class.php" );

 //создаем класс и сразу переключаемся на немецкий т.к по-умолчанию у нас язык русский
$lang = new Lang("de");

//Выводим перевод сообщения "Account disabled" предположим для страницы авторизации на текущем языке
echo $lang->getLanguage()."> ".$lang->t('login','Account disabled')."\n";

//Переключаем текущий язык на русский
$lang->setlanguage("ru");

//Выводим сообщение с подставлением параметра внутрь текста перевода уже из другого файла переводов
echo $lang->getLanguage()."> ".$lang->t('users', 'Username `@username` is invalid', ['@username' => 'vasya_pupkin'])."\n";
```

Примерно так работают классы переводов во всех популярных `php`-фреймворках, на которые я Вам и советую перейти дабы не мучиться с написанием собственных велосипедов.

Надеюсь я Вам помог.

P.S Для удобства можете переделать вызовы функций класса на статические (если Вам лень создавать экземпляр класса) :)